# Sending var over socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

ii'm new to node.js and socket.io. I'm trying to track gesture from phone to pc. I'm correctly sending text but i'm not able to send data

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- <body ontouchstart="showCoordinates(event)" ontouchmove="showCoordinates(event)"> -->
<body ontouchstart="countTouches(event)" ontouchend="countTouches(event)">
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect();
function countTouches(event) {
var x = event.touches.length;
socket.emit('clicked');
}
socket.on('buttonUpdate', function(countTouches){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
io.on('connection', function(client){
client.on('clicked', function(data) {
//send a message to ALL connected clients
io.emit('buttonUpdate');
console.log('click!');
  });
});
http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

I got the touch count in my phone but error in the pc
Error from console: Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the data on emit from the server and in the client you are receiving `countTouches` but providing value of `x`. Try with the below code.

```js
io.on('connection', function(client){
client.on('clicked', function(data) {
//send a message to ALL connected clients
console.log(data);
io.emit('buttonUpdate',data);
console.log('click!');
  });
});
http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- <body ontouchstart="showCoordinates(event)" ontouchmove="showCoordinates(event)"> -->
<body ontouchstart="countTouches(event)" ontouchend="countTouches(event)">
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect();
function countTouches(event) {
var x = event.touches.length;
socket.emit('clicked',x);
}
socket.on('buttonUpdate', function(countTouches){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = countTouches;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thnx dude, yeap, i know i wasn't sending data to server, now it work correctly. Many thnx